# Hibernate one to one for two columns (two fields of the same type in an Entity class)

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Suppose I have a Noughts and Crosses game (tic tac toe):

**games**:

```
id    crosses_player_id    noughts_player_id...
```

**players**:

```
id    alignment    game_id
```

Since there are only 2 players, I see no need to create a separate table, so I did it like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "games")
public class Game {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "game")
    @JoinColumn(name = "crosses_player_id")
    private Player crossesPlayer;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "game")
    @JoinColumn(name = "noughts_player_id")
    private Player noughtsPlayer;

    private List<Move> moves = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();
...
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "players")
public class Player {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false)
    private User user;

    private enum Alignment {
        NOUGHTS, CROSSES
    };
    private Alignment alignment;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = ?)
    private Game game;
...
```

However I'm not sure what to put inside `@OneToOne(mappedBy = ?)` in `Player` class.

The closest answer I've found is this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13944195/4759176

```
class TeamPlay {
    @ManyToOne
    Team homeTeam;

    @ManyToOne
    Team awayTeam;
}

class Team {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="homeTeam")
    Set<TeamPlay> homeTeamPlays;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="awayTeam")
    Set<TeamPlay> awayTeamPlays;
}
```

However it looks like `Team` class can have many possible games, while in my case 1 player has only ever 1 game. A player is basically users's id, game's id and the allighment (noughts or crosses) and after the game is over that same player is never referenced again from any new games. Maybe I should do it like this:

**Player**:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "crossesPlayer")
private Game crossesGame;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "noughtsPlayer")
private Game noughtsGame;
```

but then, a player can *only* be either noughts or crosses player, so one of those fields would always be null?

Comment: [Here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) is a good example on how to map the one to one relationships.

Comment: You should read the javadoc and understand the bidirectional relationships. One side must be owning the relation, the other one should include the mappedBy parameter.

Comment: @cghislai I understand that. I've done join tables before. I'm not sure how to handle this particular situation though

Comment: just let your player own the relation ship - dont add any mappedBy in that entity

Comment: think of it this way: you want one player to be linked to exactly one game. Can you enforce it by having a reference to the game in the player table or two references to two players in the game table?

Answer (score 3):

@parsecer ... For me, your problem lies in a misconception about your data model; quoting you:

> A player is basically users's id, game's id and the allighment (noughts or crosses) and after the game is over that same player is never referenced again from any new games

This means that "Game" is a strong entity and should not have references (i.e., foreign keys) to Players (i.e., the table "games" should not contain the columns: crosses_player_id, noughts_player_id) ... it also means that "Player" is a weak entity that only exists in the context of a "Game" (so, here is OK to have a foreign column to game) ...

Assuming all this, your model becomes cleaner and also your mapping, for example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "players")
public class Player {
    /**
     * Player's ID.
     */
    @Id
    private int id;

    /**
     * Game to which this Player belongs.
     */
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "game_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Game game;

    /**
     * Player's alignment in the game.
     */
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Alignment alignment;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "games")
public class Game {
    /**
     * Game's Id.
     */
    @Id
    private int id;

    /**
     * Players in this game.
     */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "game", cascade = PERSIST)
    @MapKey(name = "alignment")
    private Map<Alignment, Player> players = new HashMap<>();

    ...

    public List<Player> getPlayers() {
        return Arrays.asList( this.players.values() );
    }

    public Player getCrossesPlayer() {
        return this.players.get(Alignment.CROSSES);
    }

    public Player getNoughtesPlayer() {
        return this.players.get(Alignment.NOUGHTES);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'm going to try it. However, I wonder if there is a way to do it without putting the two players into any sort of collection and just leaving them as two fields in the Game class?

Answer (score 0):

```
 @ManyToOne(optional=false) 
 @JoinColumn(name="game_id")
 private Game game;
```

The OneToOne from Game on the Player will already create the relationship you want between these entities. With the ManyToOne with Joining on the Games primary key, you will be able to see what game a player is particing in (from the players view on the data). 
With that data logic, at maximum two players could participate in a game on the data layer. However, you could still create a Player and asign him a game that he doesn't play in.

```
Player player1ThatDoesentPlay // = new Player(...); 
player1ThatDoesentPlay.setGame(thatGame) // with thatGame could already have the participating players
```

I would suggest you create a method like

```
Game checkandsetGame(Game game){
if (game.crossesplayer == null | game.noughtsplayer == null && game != null){
return setGame(game);
    }
// else {probably want to throw an error here, that indicates that the player couldn't be assigned to a game}
}
```

In general I suggest you overthink your data schema and maybe do something like @Carlitos Way suggested

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer a bit more? Maybe by explaining the code?

Answer (score 0):

In your model, you want a 1-1 relation between your game and your player. But two players will share a game, so a single game id may be referenced multiple time from the player table, but a single player may only be referenced once from the game table.

One thing you got wrong is the use of the `mappedBy` attribute, which is to be used on the non-owning side of the relation. It tells JPA 'Im referenced from that foreign key in that other table. Please fetch it for me and reference it here'. Be aware that you will have to maintain both side of the relation, that is, when you call `game.setPlayer(player)`, you will have to ensure you call `player.setGame(game)` as well. Also note that while it is probably ok for @OneToOne relations, this is not scalable and you better avoid using it.

You game-player relation is defined by their alignement. In fact, your player entity seems to define the relation between an user and a game.

The solution I would come for your use case would be to use a `GamePosition` table that will allow you to enforce that a single player is only part of a single game.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "players")
public class Player {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false)
    private User user;    
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "game")
public class Game {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "game_position")
public class GamePosition {

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="player_id", unique=true)
    // Making this column unique will prevent a single player to be part of two games
    private Player player;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="game_id")
    private Game game;

    @Enumarated
    private Alignement alignement;

}
```

Then if you want bidirectional relations, you can use the mappedBy attribute.
In the player table:

```
  @OneToOne(mappedBy="player")
  private GamePosition gamePosition;
```

or in the game table:

```
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="game")
  private List<GamePosition> gamePositions;
```