# JPA Hibernate ConstraintViolationException

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm working with JPA/Hibernate/Spring for the first time. I'm trying to build a simple workout tracker but I've ran into a problem when populating fields, e.g.:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

Here are my classes (only including what I believe are the relevant parts):

Exercise:

```
@Entity
public class Exercise implements Serializable, IExercise {
public Exercise(){
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long exerciseID;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "exerciseName")
private String exerciseName;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "reps")
private Long reps;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "workoutID", nullable = false)
private Workout workout;
```

Workout:

```
@Entity
public class Workout implements Serializable, IWorkout {
public Workout(){
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long workoutID;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "workoutName")
private String workoutName;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "description")
private String description;


@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        mappedBy = "workout")
private Collection<Exercise> exercises;
```

WorkoutService:

```
@Service
public class WorkoutService implements IWorkoutService {

@Autowired
WorkoutRepository workoutRepository;
@Autowired
ExerciseRepository exerciseRepository;

public void saveWorkout(Workout workout) {
    System.out.println("Current count of workout repository: ");
    System.out.println(workoutRepository.count());
    System.out.println("Saving workout...");
    workoutRepository.save(workout);
    System.out.println("Updated count of workout repository: ");
    System.out.println(workoutRepository.count());
}

@Override
public void deleteWorkout() {
    System.out.println("Before delete: " + workoutRepository.count());
    workoutRepository.deleteById(new Long(1));
    System.out.println("After delete: " + workoutRepository.count());
}

public void saveExercise(Exercise exercise) {
    System.out.println("Current count of exercise repository: ");
    System.out.println(exerciseRepository.count());
    System.out.println("Saving exercise...");
    exerciseRepository.save(exercise);
    System.out.println("Updated count of exercise repository: ");
    System.out.println(exerciseRepository.count());
}

@Override
public void deleteExercise() {
    System.out.println("Before delete: " + exerciseRepository.count());
    exerciseRepository.deleteById(new Long(1));
    System.out.println("After delete: " + exerciseRepository.count());
}
```

}

The error throws when I hit this line in the Service:

```
exerciseRepository.save(exercise);
```

I've looked at multiple threads but I just don't know how to troubleshoot this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    2018-09-26 13:36:00 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select 
     exercise0_.exerciseid as exerciseid1_0_0_, exercise0_.description as description2_0_0_, exercise0_.exercise_name as exercise_name3_0_0_, exercise0_.reps as reps4_0_0_, exercise0_.workoutid as workoutid5_0_0_ from exercise exercise0_ where exercise0_.exerciseid=?
2018-09-26 13:36:00 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select exercise_seq.nextval from dual
2018-09-26 13:36:00 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select exercise_seq.nextval from dual
2018-09-26 13:36:00 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into exercise (description, exercise_name, reps, workoutid, exerciseid) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2018-09-26 13:36:00 WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1400, SQLState: 23000
2018-09-26 13:36:00 ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("<username>"."EXERCISE"."WORKOUTID")

2018-09-26 13:36:00 ERROR o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl - HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
2018-09-26 13:36:00 INFO  o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-09-26 13:36:00 ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:803)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:784)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
    at depaul.Main.main(Main.java:27)
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:259)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:540)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:532)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:304)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy106.save(Unknown Source)
    at depaul.service.WorkoutService.saveExercise(WorkoutService.java:39)
    at depaul.Main.createExercise(Main.java:87)
    at depaul.Main.run(Main.java:45)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:800)
    ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3547)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:600)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1437)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:494)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3245)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2451)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:536)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("<username>"."EXERCISE"."WORKOUTID")

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1054)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:623)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:612)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:226)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:59)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:910)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1119)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3780)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1343)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3865)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3845)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1061)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
    ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("<username>"."EXERCISE"."WORKOUTID")
```

Comment: can you post the full exception stacktrace maybe at the bottom of the stacktrace there is a cause

Comment: Your mapping is incorrect. If one side of the association is a OneToMany, the other one can't be a OneToOne. It's a ManyToOne.

Comment: apologies. i updated my original code (I had been desperately trying other associations and when I posted it here I forgot I had left it like that). I still get the same error.

Comment: The error is pretty clear. you insert null into exercise.workout_id. this column is mapped to Exercise.workout. So that means that the workout field of the Exercise you're inserting is null. Make sure it's not null.

Comment: Okay. I understand what you're saying, but for example: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-jpa-hibernate-oracle
the Player class in this link has no field "team_id", it's a many to one join with the Team classes team_id column. Similarly, my Exercise class doesn't have a field for workoutID (and when I've tried to add it, more errors are thrown). I guess my confusion lies in where the workoutID for the Exercise class is being searched for.

Comment: You have not read my comment. workout_id is mapped to `Exercise.workout`. I.e. the field `workout` of the class `Exercise`. This field (`workout`) is null in the `Exercise` object that you're trying to insert. It may not be null.

Comment: oh gee. really overthought that one. Thanks, I got it working.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your error:

`Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("<username>"."EXERCISE"."WORKOUTID")`

Workoutid from exercise is null

Comment: right - but how do I get it to not be? I tried setting a field in my Exercise class to set a workoutID but it just throws even more errors related to the relationship between Workout and Exercise.

Comment: i think you should have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811844/jpa-onetomany-and-manytoone-relationships because you want map a oneToMany to a oneToOne ... i think it should be a manyToOne

Comment: sorry - i'll update my post but currently it is a oneToMany to a manyToOne. still giving the same error.