# How to join Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

```
public class Primary{
    private long id;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
        strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY
    )
    @Column(
        name = "id"
    )
    public void getId(){return id;}

    //other vars
}

public class Secondary{
    //other vars
    private Primary primary;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "primary_id", unique = true)
    public Primary getPrimary(){return primary;}
}
```

From this, it is pretty easy to get a Primary Object from a Secondary Object. However, how do I get Secondary Object from a Primary Object without selecting twice in Hibernate?

Answer (score 1):

The `Primary` class should look like this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="primary", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
private List<Secondary> secondaries;
// getter and setter
```

And you should make a small modification in `Secondary`:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "id", unique = true)
public Primary getPrimary(){return primary;}
```

Cause join column should refer to the joined field(`id`) in `Primary`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer could be quite different based on what you are looking for.

Based on your current mapping, assuming you have a `Primary` instance on hand, you can get its corresponding `Secondary` by querying.  E.g. by HQL:

```
from Secondary s where s.primary = :primary
```

and pass in your primary as the parameter.

If you are looking for way to navigate from a `Primary` object instance, you could have created a bi-directional mapping:

```
class Primary {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="primary", ...)
    private Set<Secondary> secondaries;
}

class Secondary {
    @ManyToOne
    private Primary primary;
}
```

You could refer to my (very old) answer on related question on how to define it.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/13812047/395202

However, simply having a bi-directional relationship DOES NOT avoid "selecting twice", **if your "selecting twice" means running 2 SQL queries in DB**.

To reduce such round-trip, there are several way to solve.  First one is to declare the relationship as EAGER fetch.  However this is a way that I don't usually recommend so I won't go deeper.

Another (imho, more appropriate) way is to do a join fetch when you are fetching `Primary`.  To fetch the `Primary` instance with its related `Secondary` instances, use a HQL like :

```
from Primary p left join fetch p.secondaries where ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this Setter method in the Secondary Class

```
public Primary getPrimary() {
        return primary;
    }
```

And get the primary object from Secondary Class